# What is this .IMG-schema and how can I use it to decode CDR?

Tags: decode, asn.1

I need to decode a binary CDR file which starts like this in hex:

```
)\x00\x00\x01\x01\x00~\x1f\x14\x15\x82\x000\xf0\xff\xff\xff\xff%\x01&\x16\x16\x83\x02\x00\x81y$\x17\x05\t\x12! F4\x08\x13\x02\xff\xac\x00)%\x01&\x16\x00\x98J\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff
```

To decode this I have a .IMG file which I was told is the ASN.1 schema. The file .IMG-file looks like

```
...Y00AN1MX.PAC 3.1-0 10/08/24    GSMENVMH.PAC 26.9-0...
...
#Form_end                                                                                                                   
                                                                                                                           
#Format_type                                (1)                                                                             
#Message_number                             (dd98)                                                                          
#Format_type_name                           (MOC)                                                                           
#Record_length                              (675)                                                                           
#Output_mode                                (BIN)                                                                           
#Output_device                              (NOT_USED)                                                                      
                                                                                                                            
#Header                                                                                                                     
record_length                               @(W(1),0,W(1),0,1)                                                              
record_type                                 @(BCD(1),2,C(1),2,2)                                                            
record_number                               @(BCD(4),3,DW(1),3,3)                                                           
record_status                               @(C(1),7,C(1),7,4)                                                              
check_sum                                   @(W(1),8,W(1),8,5)                                                              
call_reference                              @(C(5),10,C(5),10,6)                                                            
exchange_id                                 @(C(10),15,C(10),15,7)
```

This does not look  like ASN.1 schema to me. Can this be transferred to ASN.1 or used somehow to decode the initial CDR?

Comment: I strongly suspect that the "CDR" tag is not applicable. That CDR tag refers to an ancient LISP primitive. And while ASN.1 is equally ancient, it's entirely unrelated to LISP.  The meaning of CDR in the context of this question is probably 'Call Detail Record'.

Comment: @MSalters thank you you are totally right, CDR stands for "Call Detail Record", so I removed the CDR tag. Seems like there is no equivalent tag.  But ASN.1 is still right, as this is in the contect of Abstract Syntax Notation. The file should be encoded via ASN.1 in a certain schema, "Call Detail Record"

Comment: ASN.1 tag is also incorrect, as clearly, neither the data nor the description file are ASN.1 but some proprietary binary format defined by the NE vendor (which I guess is Nokia here).